# Retrieving the indices of elements within a list of lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Suppose I have the following:

```
lists = [[1, 3, 5], [1, 2, 3], [3, 5, 7], [1, 4, 8], [2, 3, 4, 5]]
```

I want to retrieve the the indices of each element within the list of lists e.g. `1` occurs in:

```
lists[0], lists[1], lists[3]
```

How can this be done?

Comment: Do you mean digit 1 or number 1? I.e., should it count the list element, if it were 512? And what have you tried, why did it fail?

Comment: Did one of the below solutions help? If so, feel free to accept, or ask for clarification.

Answer (score 2):

You can use list comprehension to achieve this:

```
lists = [[1, 3, 5], [1, 2, 3], [3, 5, 7], [1, 4, 8], [2, 3, 4, 5]]

x = [i for i, elem in enumerate(lists) if 1 in elem]
```

Comment: `I want to retrieve the the indices of each element`. On that basis, I strongly recommend you do not use a list comprehension for each number. You will be applying O(m*n) complexity, whereas only O(n) is required.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an O(n) solution using `collections.defaultdict`. The idea is to create a dictionary storing each index for each number. To avoid duplicates, we use `set`.

For example, retrieve the indices for `1` via `d[1]` for a set or `list(d[1])` for a list.

```
L = [[1, 3, 5], [1, 2, 3], [3, 5, 7], [1, 4, 8], [2, 3, 4, 5]]

from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(set)

for idx, lst in enumerate(L):
    for num in lst:
        d[num].add(idx)

print(d)

defaultdict(set,
            {1: {0, 1, 3},
             3: {0, 1, 2, 4},
             5: {0, 2, 4},
             2: {1, 4},
             7: {2},
             4: {3, 4},
             8: {3}})
```